# ALV List Viewer for single entry in IW29/39 transaction

Tags: vba, list, transactions, sap-erp, sap-gui

I'm calling SAP transaction from VBA to automate report. When I'm using transaction like IW39 my output display is a list shown with SAP ALV List Viewer. It's very useful to export to VBA where I have a function to do it automatically.

[image: ALV display]

But sometimes I have an issue in some particular case: when my hit list consists of only one line. SAP replaces ALV with something not very useful to export with VBA.

[image: Not ALV display]

**My question is:** is there a way to change the display mode to "ALV-always" when there is single line in a hit list?

*A clue: when I start IW39 tcode and when I have a single line, the result is displayed as an IW33 tcode. So when I come back to transaction I stay in IW33 query.*

Comment: How do you call the notification list from VBA? Give us the code.

Answer (score 1):

As your screenshots show, you speak about IW**29** (Display Notifications), not IW39, however, their logic is quite similar.
The switch, which defines how to display results - via ALV or directly via IW23/IW33 - is **hard coded** in `IW29` logic (which is `RIQMEL20` report) and cannot be changed that easy.

However, while learning the code, I found out that the results are listed correctly, in ALV, even for single entry if tcode is executed **in background mode**, The corresponding program check exists in source code.

So these are possible solutions as I see them :

- Create dummy transaction (e.g. ZIW29) and execute target report in batch like this

  ```
  SUBMIT RIQMEL20 AND RETURN.
  ```
- Create dummy transaction and run target report exporting results to memory

  ```
  SUBMIT RIQMEL20 EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY.
  ```
- Directly call target transaction (IW29/39) in batch and export results to memory

  ```
  DATA: lt_bdcdata TYPE TABLE OF bdcdata, ls_options TYPE ctu_params.
  ls_options-dismode = 'N'. " This is to set the batch input mode

  CALL TRANSACTION 'IW29' USING lt_bdcdata OPTIONS FROM ls_options.
  IMPORT data_tab TO it_out FROM MEMORY ID 'XYZ'.
  ```
- Any combinations of the above.
- Playing with AS ABAP [operation modes](https://sapbasisdurgaprasad.blogspot.com.by/2011/06/how-to-setup-operation-modes-in-sap.html) (dialog/background) thus forcing server to set `sy-binpt` variable to `X`.
- Revoke authorization to start IW*9 transactions in foreground and start them only via `SA38`.

By and large, one can conclude that it is **unachievable** to achieve this by means of VBA (i.e. without ABAP or BASIS intervention).